# 100% Height layout with fixed header + overflow without JS

Tags: html, css

i would like to achieve specific layout:

```
------------------------------
Header - flexable height depending on content
------------------------------
Content with overflow filling remaining space to 100% height
------------------------------
+ Some space after (padding/bottom?) ( 70px for example)
------------------------------
```

And this should have 100% height and 100% width of document. It seemed i cant use divs to achiev this so i was trying tables but i cant find way how to do that with crossbrowser compatibility (last try was working in everything except IE (of course) and was not well written). Could somebody give me some example working like that?

I was looking at similar questions here but i cant find this specific situation.

*PS: sorry for my english - not my primary language*

EDIT: Some code i actualy have but it works on webkit now

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #fixedHeaderTable
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0px solid black;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #fixedHeaderTable td
        {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        #fixedHeaderTable .headerRow
        {
            height: 0px;
        }

        #fixedHeaderTable .headerRow td
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #T
        {
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
          #content {
             padding-bottom: 140px;
          }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="fixedHeaderTable">
        <thead style="height: 0px;">
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <td style="height: 1px;">
                Header
            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="height: 100%;">
        <tr style="height: 100%;">
            <td style="padding-bottom: 70px; height: 100%;">
                <div class="box" id="T">
                Long content
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be more specific, on what you tried and where you are failing to implement a particular feature.

Comment: I was trying tables but FF, IE have problems with respecting overflow on td and height: 0px on header to allow flexibility ... its possible to make somehow FF work but IE is resisting every atempt .. most of them was later just test&fail system so its hard to be more specific on that ... i have figured out FF needs height:100% on diferent elements than webkit to make it atleast paritaly working but thats all im affraid

Comment: You should post some code, so the community can have a look at the problem. I guess that you need: `height: 100vh` on Content

Comment: Code added, i was hoping somebody could post me some clear example without trying to modify my code ... it is realy wrong at this state (too many not succesfull atempts to make it work everywhere) and works only on webkit now so i was not posting it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic solution, with flexible height on the `header` and scrolling content in `main`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;                            /*  fill remaining space  */
  padding: 10px 10px 70px;            /*  70px bottom padding   */
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
      <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking about flexes but - how crossbrowser compatible it is? :) ... And scrollbar should be only in content div - header should behave like fixed, thx anyway.

Comment: @astromedia Updated my answer. `flex` has +95% browser support, all new browser + 2 versions back, also, there is no other working solution if you want a flexible header (one can do it with table, though IE has issues). The good thing, in your case, is that on unsupported browsers, the page will still work but header will scroll with it, so I wouldn't hesitate a second doing it like this

Comment: Ok thanks, it seems working in major browsers and to be easy enough to modify so im taking it as answer. I hope it will not break something after more testing/content adding but for now it seems good :)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe (if I've understood it correctly) is relatively straightforward - two block-level elements, a fixed `header` and scrolling `main` beneath it, each with 100% `width`.

**Example:**

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

header, main {
display: block;
}

header {
position: fixed;
z-index: 6;
width: 100%;
height: 140px;
font-size: 36px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(191,0,0);
}

main {
position: relative;
top: 140px;
height: calc(100vh - 140px - 70px);
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<header>
Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header Header 
</header>

<main>
Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main
Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main
</main>
```

Comment: Thx for your time but i was actualy ment viewport as you explaining it ... i was trying to make some illustration to make it easyer to understand, i hope it helps - [image](http://imgur.com/a/tZ3tr)

Comment: Okay, that's fine - I've tweaked it a little bit, so the answer above should now represent one approach to what you are trying to achieve with a fixed `header` and a `main` which scrolls to reveal the overflow.

Comment: Thanks, seems better, one thing more if i could ask - that header should not have specified height (140px) but be "flexable" - change height depending on content ... that was one of things why this was hard to implement for me :)

Comment: You can apply `height: auto;` to the `header` which means the `header` will then adjust its own height relative to the content it contains. But the problem is... how to tell the browser where the top of `main` should begin. This is straightforward with javascript, but I'm racking my brains as to how to do it in CSS alone.